# faster approach to multiples of 3 and 5

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why is this approach faster?

```
x=list(range(0,1000000,3))
z=list(range(0,1000000,5))
y=list(range(0,1000000,15))
%timeit sum(x)+sum(z)-sum(y)
24 ms ± 1.25 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Why is list comprehension slower?

```
%timeit sum([i for i in range(1000000) if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0])
205 ms ± 7.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

I thought list comprehension suppose to be faster. Is there any other approach that is faster than these two?

Comment: You are comparing two different things, the list comprehension that you have, has to loop through all the 100000000 including those that are not needed eg 1,2,4,6, etc. This is not the same as the x,y and z which do not contain these elements.

Comment: @Onyambu Got it. That explains why it took longer to execute. Thanks.

Comment: For even faster: `sum(range(0,1000000,3)) == 3*X*(X+1)//2` with `X=1000000//3`...

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28936/project-euler-1-multiples-of-3-and-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is a list comprehension to make it faster take out the brackets, example:

```
%timeit sum(i for i in range(1000000) if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0)
```

Output:

```
10 loops, best of 3: 47.5 ms per loop
```

But the second one can be made faster too, without using `list` outside:

```
x=range(0,1000000,3)
z=range(0,1000000,5)
y=range(0,1000000,15)
%timeit sum(x)+sum(z)-sum(y)
```

Output:

```
1 loop, best of 3: 287 ms per loop
```

> But same thing you will still be thinking why is it still faster?
>
> > Because you're still iterating trough the range in the second example
> >
> > The other one is just summing generators

To make it faster do:

```
print(1000000//3 + 1000000//5 - 1000000//15)
```

---

```
%timeit 1000000//3 + 1000000//5 - 1000000//15
```

Time taken:

```
10000000 loops, best of 3: 31.3 ns per loop
```

Comment: This is taking 287ms per loop, while the one OP posted is taking 24ms per loop.. doesn't that show that the one OP has is faster than this one????

Comment: @Onyambu Oh i miss-copied it

Comment: Keep in mind that generator expressions often have higher CPU overhead than equivalent list comprehensions; their primary advantage is in fixed, low memory usage, not in speed. It's only in cases where the result isn't fully consumed (e.g. because it's looped over with an early `break`), or when the result is large enough that the memory usage starts pushing you out of caches and main RAM that you're likely to see significant speed improvements.

Answer (score 0):

There are likely two parts that slow down the second:  the remainder function (%) and having to loop through all of the items.  The first only needs to count up by multiples of 3, 5, or 15 until it reaches the number.

If you really want to optimize it the most, though, you should just use integer division:  `1000000//3 + 1000000//5 - 1000000//15`

EDIT:  This does not answer the question, as Onyambu commented below.  A faster approach would be finding the averages and multiplying by the number.  For example, the following would calculate the sum of the multiples of 3 less than or equal to 1000000:  `((1000000//3)*(1000000//3 * 3 + 3))//2`.  This finds the number of multiples of 3 not more than 1000000 and multiplies it by the average of the largest multiple (`1000000//3 * 3`) and the smallest multiple (`3`).

Comment: Please look at OP's code and you will realize it is totally different from what you are suggesting